# Is it possible to disable forced monospace in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal

In Terminal.app in Mavericks, regardless of which font you use, the font metrics are ignored and forced monospacing is applied instead. Is there a way to disable this?

Ridiculous example of the effect:
[image: Terminal using Zapfino]

Comment: This is a good one, I can't find a way to disable it. Why would you want to though? Many terminal programs depends on fonts being monospaced in order to properly display tables and data.

Comment: I have custom modified a monospaced font to include half width spaces which allow me to center things more precisely. I know it's extremely nitpicky, but after I went to all the trouble of editing the font and getting good display in my editor, it was a let down to not have the same effect in the terminal.